# Name is not printing in the screen in java

Tags: java, jsp

I have a event type and event organizer.Based on the event type,event organizer will search.All the functions are working properly ,but name is not printing on the screen.Here is the code.

```
<tr>
                <td class="bg1" width="25%">Event Organizer User Type </td>
                <td class="bg1" width="25%"><edu:select name="usertype" fieldlist="<%=userType%>" selvalue='STUDENT' noselect="true" onclick="TypeValue(this)"/> </td>

                <td class="bg1" width="25%"><div id="ele">Student Id<edu:prnStar /><a href=# onClick='openwindow2()'><img src='../images/util/final.gif' name='search' width='20' height='20' alt='Search' border='0'></a></div></td>
                <td class="bg1" width="25%"> <input type="text" name="eventorganizer" id="eventorganizer" maxlength="25" onblur="validateField('SPLALPHA',this)"/> </td-->
         </tr>
```

Here are the functions

```
function TypeValue(as){

ttype=as.value;

if(ttype=="STUDENT"){

    document.getElementById('ele').innerHTML="Student Id<edu:prnStar/><a href=# onClick='openwindow2()'><img src='../images/util/final.gif' name='search' width='20' height='20' alt='Search' border='0'></a>";

}else if(ttype=="STAFF"){

    document.getElementById('ele').innerHTML="Staff Id<edu:prnStar/><a href=# onClick='openwindow1()'><img src='../images/util/final.gif' name='search' width='20' height='20' alt='Search' border='0'></a>";

}else{

    document.getElementById('ele').innerHTML="Guest/Visitor Id<edu:prnStar/><a href=# onClick='openwindow3()'><img src='../images/util/final.gif' name='search' width='20' height='20' alt='Search' border='0'></a>";
}

document.edufrm.typee.value=ttype;
```

}

//For Dynamic Staff Search

```
function openwindow1()
{

    window.open('EduManage.jsp?control=search1&searchno=5_0s1&position=2','','width=790,height=420,left=0,top=70,scrollbars=1,location=no,status=no,resizable=yes');
}

//For Dynamic Student Search

function openwindow2()
{
    window.open('EduManage.jsp?control=search1&searchno=3_0s1&position=2','','width=790,height=420,left=0,top=70,scrollbars=1,location=no,status=no,resizable=yes');
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ....

Comment: Can you share the compiled source, I want to see what is the value of <edu:prnStar/>

Comment: <edu:prnStar/> this is just a mandatory symbol(*) @SaurabhJhunjhunwala

Comment: Where is this name which you want to get printed?

Comment: in the text box